# How to make a templated function that references itself in c#

Tags: c#

I want to have a container class that holds an object implementing an interface T. When this container object creates its field, it would then tell that inner object it was created passing itself. However this is a circular template reference and I am not sure how to make this compile. The below is what I would like to accomplish.

```
public interface ISerializableItem 
{
  void Created(JsonDatabaseObject<THIS CLASS SOMEHOW> item); //This is the the place I cannot figure out
}

public class JsonDatabaseObject<T> where T: SerializableItem, new()
{
  public T o;
  public static JsonDatabaseObject<T> Fetch()
  {
    JsonDatabaseObject<T> item = new JsonDatabaseObject<T>();
    item.o = new T();
    item.o.Created(this);
  }
}
```

Is there some syntactic sugar to make this idea work?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the container object inside the thing contained by it?  The circular issues are a clue that the design can be improved, IMO.  You might be better off refactoring `JsonDatabaseObject<T>` to contain _two_ things: one is the instance of T, and the other is the collection of properties you want to pass into `Created`.  In other words, don't pass the container down, pull something else out of the container to give to `item.o.Created`.  (Feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); more scope on the problem could help.)

Comment: It was so the class inside can find database specific things out about it, but you are probably right, I could put those somehow that are generic and can be passed in.